# document.getElementById() VS. getElementById()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

It is common for me to register javascript functions for certain events by doing something like:

```
myBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "Validate(getElementById('"+txtFirstName.ClientID + "'));");
```

I've always used `getElementById` by itself, or in other words, sans document being prepended to it. But I'm having pages break on me lately when I try to use `getElementById` instead of `document.getElementById`. Why is this? Oddly, I have a website where one page allows me to use just `getElementById`, but another other page throws a javascript error because it can't find the element if I do just `getElementById`, and it'll only work if I do `document.getElementById`.

Anyone know why this is? Should I be using `document.getElementById` everywhere, regardless of whether it works without the document prefix?

EDIT:
Could it have anything to do with the fact that one page is using AJAX and the other isn't?

Comment: Hey, could you unaccept the current answer? It’s wrong, and it could mislead people that come across this question.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `getElementById()` and it works that mean that the function where it's called is running on the context of the document, that's is this == document.

So, you should ALWAYS use `document.getElementById` to avoid that kind of errors.

Anyway, I would even stop using getElementById altogether and start using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), i'm sure you'll never regret it.

Your code would look something like this if you used JQuery:

```
$("#myBtnID").click(function () { Validate($("#myTextboxID"))});
```

Comment: +1, seriously, there is a lot of utility in using a high quality JS library

Comment: Awesome. I will definately take a look at JQuery.

Comment: sorry, but your description is wrong: the current lexical environment (the 'context') is different from the object referenced by `this`; if a plain `getElementById()` works, it doesn't mean that `this == document`, but that a variable with such a name is defined in an enclosing function or the global object (aka `window`)

Comment: Well, it does not need to be (this == document), but getElementById must be defined on the current stack frame or in the current this object, or if there is a global object (i dont know if there is, i need to read about that) it must be defined on it as you say. sorry if i was inaccurate in order to make a short answer

Comment: @AlbertEin: the current `this` object is not part of the 'stack frame' - the lexical environment is built from the scopes of enclosing functions, the global object (`window`) and any object explicitly added via the `with()` statement; if you want to access properties of the object referenced by `this`, you have to do it explicitly!

Comment: @Christoph i know that the "this" object is not part of the stack frame, and i never said so. I dind't knew that you needed to call members of "this" explicitly, i just tought it behaved like other languages like C# and Java, my bad.

Now i'm intrigued, if "this" members must be referenced explicitly, and getElementById gets referenced based on the global object (window) why it would sometimes work or don't based on the enclosing function?

Comment: "Anyway, i would event stop using getElementById altogether and start using JQuery" - LOL

Comment: For such a hideously wrong answer, it has remarkably many upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Any function or variable you access without an owning object (ex: document.getElementById) will access the property from window.

So getElementById is actually window.getElementById, which isn't natively defined (unless you defined it before (ex: getElementById = document.getElementById).

Comment: Some older versions of FF and IE had this dilemma: it was window.getElementById in one and document.getElementById in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) (even if I'd recommend using libraries like prototype or jquery to be able to use the $ sign).

If you are able to use getElementById on its own, it's just because the browser you're using is doing some kind of trick to get it to work, but the correct way is to use the document variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the full `document.getElementById()`.  If you find that too verbose, you could use jQuery:

```
$('#' + id)
```

or you could create an alias at the top of your script:

```
var byID = document.getElementById;
```

Comment: your alias might not work because it doesn't bind `this` to `document`; to make it work, you'd have to use `var byID = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };`

Comment: I despise aliasing to no end, but I'm going to look into JQuery for sure. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know how to explain it but its because the getElementById() finds an element in the html structure of a page. Some browsers know that by default you want to search the document, but other browsers need that extra guidance hence document.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is indeed [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.getElementById).

The reason (speculation) it might work by itself is that depending on where you use it the current context may in fact be the document object, thus inexplicitly resulting in document.getElementById().