# Min max value in javascript, no errors showing, but code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really new to this, no errors are showing up, but code doesn't work.   Trying to get the min and max value of numbers entered in the text-box.

here's the code:

```
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <h1>Problem JavaScript</h1>
  Enter a series of numbers with spaces in between each:
  <input type="text" name="qty1" id="qty"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="calculate();">Enter</button>
</body>
</html

function calculate(){

var numInput = getElementById("qty");
var numArray = numInput.split(" ");

document.write('Min value is:', Math.min.apply(null, numArray));
document.write('Max value is:', Math.max.apply(null, numArray));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted your full HTML?

Comment: Paste your full HTML code. I see a HTML tag without closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it.

1.) `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`. See [document.getElementById() VS. getElementById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854253/document-getelementbyid-vs-getelementbyid)

2.) Calling `.split` on the element returned by `getElementById` isn't going to work, you need to do that to the element's value. ie:

```
var numInput = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var numArray = numInput.split(" ");
```

Here's a full example

```js
function calculate() {
  var numInput = document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var numArray = numInput.split(" ");

  document.write('Min value is:', Math.min.apply(null, numArray));
  document.write('Max value is:', Math.max.apply(null, numArray));
}
```

```html
<h1> Problem JavaScript</h1> Enter a series of numbers with spaces in between each:
<input type="text" id="qty">
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go" onclick="calculate()">
```

Comment: Face palm moment with the document.getElementById...Thanks so much! been staring at it for a while and couldn't figure it out....

Comment: Of course! Consider marking this answer as correct to help people find it in the future

Comment: to get the sum..i tried math.sum but that didn't work..will i need to use the .reduce?

Comment: `.reduce` will work, but as it stands, your array is actually an array of strings, not integers. So, you'll need to map it to integers first. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9d6urkr/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help..i looked at .map and .reduce but couldn't figure out how to write it to work