# Scope of inline JavaScript vs script element

Tags: javascript

If I have inline JavaScript I can get an element Id like this:

`getElementById('message')`

However, if I place it in a script element I need to specify the document object first as follows:

`document.getElementById('message')`

Why is the `document` object optional for inline JavaScript but not in a script element? Does it have something to do with a difference in scope?

Also, does it make a difference whether or not I use the `document` object in inline JavaScript?

Also, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854253/document-getelementbyid-vs-getelementbyid) says that you should always use `document`. However, this is not referring to using inline JavaScript. Is it okay to exclude `document` when using inline JavaScript? Many of the [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) online do not use `document` when using inline JavaScript.

**Update**

This is not a duplicate of the attached answer as the attached answer is not referring to inline JavaScript. Also, a number of people had indicated that the chosen answer is not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854253/document-getelementbyid-vs-getelementbyid

Comment: This link is not referring to inline JavaScript. Also, a number of people had indicated that the chosen answer is not correct.